# Is there an "Analog Crossbar Switch" that can emulate a keyboard matrix?

Tags: multiplexer

I am trying to produce keypresses on a typical keyboard matrix circuit with a microcontroller. It's easily done using CD4051BE multiplexers. However, that approach does not allow to produce simultaneous keypresses, also it's sort of bulky.

Now everybody talks of some "crossbar switches" -- a chip that has, say, 8 inputs and 8 outputs and being controlled, say by I2C, can wire any (or many) of them together.

So, I searched and have not found anything like that. Does anyone know of such a chip, please? It would also be great if it's not too rare or exotic.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic -- Or maybe you meant you are ***not*** looking for a particular model. In either case, I would re-word the question to ensure it cannot be taken to be a shopping question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I am looking for the actual name of the chip. E.g., AD747359H (example).

Comment: I'll edit your question to avoid the shopping vibe - take note.

Comment: Try searching for "crosspoint switch" and go through all the datasheets? Beware that some of these ICs do not allow all possible combinations.

Comment: There are. They are called analog switch arrays, have you searched for them? Many chips are rare, expensive, or obsolete these days, so for simple keyboard emulation, these are too high performance to justify the price. With the same price you could take a bunch of 4051 chips and IO expanders to have few simultaneous keys - are there many in addition to shift button?

Comment: I'd advise renaming your question again to ask "what category of IC can emulate a keyboard matrix" because it may still fall foul of the "no shopping" rule (answers quickly go out of date). But asking how to search for one is ok!

Answer (score 0):

> *It's easily done using CD4051BE multiplexers. However, that approach
> does not allow to produce simultaneous keypresses, also it's sort of
> bulky.*

Well, if the maximum number of simultaneous keypresses is (say) **2** then have **two** circuit layers of CD4051 multiplexers. Yes, it becomes twice as bulky but, given the chip shortages we have these days (and especially so on rarer items like cross-point switches), it might make some sense to adopt the above approach. I mean, it's not as if this is a saleable item - it sounds like you are wanting to test something and you can probably live with a solution that isn't so streamlined.

It's an option.